# dojo spinnig wheel during ajax request

Tags: dojo

I am using the code to handle the Ajax requests in Dojo. the Following code is being used:

```
dojo.xhrPost({
    url: 'getdata?id',
    handleAs: "json-comment-filtered",
    content: params,
    preventCache: true,
    load: function(data) {
        if (data.errors == undefined) {
            var jsonObj = eval(data.charges);
                for (var key in jsonObj) {
                    dojo.byId("" + mode + "_" + key).innerHTML = '<span class="rightside" >' + jsonObj[key] + '</span>';
                }

            }
        } else {
            alert(data.errors);
        }
    },
    error: function(errObj, ioArgs) {
        console.debug("Error in response");
        console.debug(errObj);
        dojo.publish("ajaxRequestCompleted");
    }
});
}
```

Code works fine, but i am unable to view the spinning icon, i tried many ways of adding the spinner after the `dojo` , but none seems to be working..

Can someone guide me on this, dojo is bit new to me and its getting hard time to figure this out. Using Dojo version 1.6

Thanks

Comment: Which spinning icon? I don't see anything of that in your code, or do you mean the spinning icon of the browser (like when you load a page)?

Comment: umm, i solved it. i will post my reply

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="toggle" style="display:none">loading...</div>  

 function showdospingicon() {
     document.getElementById('toggle').style.display = 'block';
    }
    function hidedospingicon() {
     document.getElementById('toggle').style.display = 'none';
    }
    showdospingicon();
    dojo.xhrPost({
        url: 'getdata?id',
        handleAs: "json-comment-filtered",
        content: params,
        preventCache: true,
        load: function(data) {
            hidedospingicon();
            if (data.errors == undefined) {
                var jsonObj = eval(data.charges);
                    for (var key in jsonObj) {
                        dojo.byId("" + mode + "_" + key).innerHTML = '<span class="rightside" >' + jsonObj[key] + '</span>';
                    }

                }
            } else {
                alert(data.errors);
            }
        },
        error: function(errObj, ioArgs) {
            hidedospingicon();
            console.debug("Error in response");
            console.debug(errObj);
            dojo.publish("ajaxRequestCompleted");
        }
    });
    }
```

Here is the complete code whih will in all cases, i had tested it many times.